# How to print a newline when running 'python -c'

Tags: python

The following prints the 2-characters `\` and `n` between each item in the list instead of a newline.

```
python3 -c 'import airflow.operators as air_ops;  \
    print([f"""{k}: {v}\n""" for k,v in air_ops.__dict__.items()])'
```

How can we get the desired escape character/newline when running `python -c` ?

Comment: Use 2 backslashes. The terminal will try to handle the backslashes before passing it off to the program so you just need to tell it not to. For example, the first backslash tells the terminal to let you continue writing the command on the next line.

Comment: @Locke  printed 2 backslashes ;)

Comment: Think carefully about what the equivalent Python code is, and what would happen if you ran it in a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `python3 -c` or semicolons or backslashes, actually. Your problem is that you're printing a list of strings, i.e. the for-loop is *inside* the list comprehension. String elements inside of a list will always be represented using their `repr`, which means newline characters will be escaped.

Instead, just use a loop. Literal newlines are fine for `python3 -c`. Let the print function append the trailing new line. You can leave out all the semicolons and  backslashes.

```
$ python3 -c 'd = {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}
> for k, v in d.items():
>     print(f"{k}: {v}")
> '
k1: v1
k2: v2
```

Comment: I'm not seeing it yet but will trust you on it. Will come back to better understand